# Uniformly distribute spatial points over a given extent R

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r, extents, distribution

Within a shapefile I am given an integer attribute that indicates the number of points that will need to be evenly (uniformly) distributed over the associated polygons extent. These spatial points will need to be stored in a separate shapefile.

Comment: What does "evenly (uniformly)" mean here? Evenly spaced out in some way? On a triangle or square lattice?